# How to apply Mysql AND/OR clause in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I am trying to make a MySQL query inside Laravel.

```
> "select * from users u where (name like
> '%".$request->search_string."%' or email like
> '%".$request->search_string."%') and (user_type=2)";
```

I tried the code below

```
public function searchUsers(Request $request){
        $query = DB::table('users as u');
        $query->where('u.user_type',2);
        $query->where(function($query,$request){
            $query->orwhere('u.name','LIKE','%'.$request->search_string.'%');
            $query->orwhere('u.email','LIKE','%'.$request->search_string.'%');
        });
        $result['all_users'] = $query->get();
    return Response::json($result);
}
```

But I am getting the following error

> Missing argument 2 for
>   App\Http\Controllers\PatientController::App\Http\Controllers{closure}()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have syntax error in where clause. See this:

```
public function searchUsers(Request $request){
        $query = DB::table('users as u');
        $query->where('u.user_type',2);
        $query->where(function($query)use($request){ // Here  is the change
                    //  ^^ Pass only one parameter to closure function and pass `$request` in `use` function
            $query->orwhere('u.name','LIKE','%'.$request->search_string.'%');
            $query->orwhere('u.email','LIKE','%'.$request->search_string.'%');
        });
        $result['all_users'] = $query->get();
    return Response::json($result);
}
```